# Can boost::program_options parse stdin string from pipe?

Tags: c++, python, boost, pipe

Not parsing the parameters in the beginning but parse the input string read from a pipe at some time the program has already run for some time. Can boost::program_options do this？ Thanks.
**EDIT:**
 I have to test a c++ program a lot of times with different parameters in python. I want to pass parameters through subprocess.PIPE to change the program's behavior.

Comment: Could you give a concrete example of what you're trying to achieve? It is unclear what "the parameters in the beginning" means.

Comment: I mean parse the string got from gets function in the c++ program.

Comment: It sounds like this is not a boost::program_options problem but rather a question of to generate the right command line that invokes your application?!

Comment: this sounds like a python question, I'm removing the boost-program-options tag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't imagine why not. That said, why are you trying to pipe the options to the program? Presumably you're looking at an option set that's too lengthy to type at every invocation of the program. If so, program_options has a really nice way to incorporate configuration files so that they'll be examined for options before the command line.

As always, [there's some great documentation and examples available](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/doc/html/program_options/tutorial.html#id2500303) from Boost that explains this in detail.

EDIT: Thanks for the clarification. If you're looking to deal with piping input to or from subprocesses in Python, then subprocess.PIPE is your friend.

Comment: I mean parse the string got from gets function in the c++ program.